# Didn't see or wasn't/weren't seeing? , simple sistuation but makes me confused

Tags: grammar

eg

1. At 7 pm yesterday, I was sitting on the chair, looking at the lake but I (wasn't seeing or didn't see) anything strange
2. While I was walking on the street, I found a wallet, I was looking around to give it back but I
   (wasn't seeing or didn't see) anyone
3. I was looking for him for 2 hours ,but I (wasn't seeing or didn't see) him

OR all the sistuations are only correct with the past simple

Comment: _Didn't see_ is fine in all three sentences (or _couldn't see_ if you were actively looking for something).

Comment: Correct spelling "situation"

Answer (score 1):

"didn't" would be the usual way of saying it.

But "wasn't" *can* be grammatically correct.
As always, context is important.

> I was looking at the lake for what seemed like hours, but no matter how hard I studied it I wasn't seeing anything strange, not until Bill pointed out that what looked like a log was actually something quite different.
> And then I *was* seeing something strange, and wishing I weren't.

The use of "was" make it an on-going action, not simply something that happened.